# Display message and rerun the code using gWidgets in R

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

```
x <- gconfirm("Run Program?",title="gConfirm")

if (x){
    w <- gwindow(title="List of Programs",visible=TRUE)
    g = ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, cont=w)   
    glabel("Please select the Program", cont=g)
    ptype <- c("A","B")
    temp <- gcombobox(ptype , cont=g)
    addHandlerChanged(temp , handler=function(...){})
    gbutton("Run", cont=g,handler = function(...){
    print(svalue(temp)
    dispose(g)
    runagain <- gconfirm("Run again?",title="gConfirm")
    if(runagain){
     ## If user clicks okay, I want to start running again from the third line of the code, w <- gwindow......)**
     }
}
```

Can anyone hint a work around that? Also how do I display the svalue(temp) in to similar UI box instead of printing it on the console. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First of all, to display a UI box for svalue(temp), you can do `gmessage(svalue(temp))`. As for your other question on re-running the code, what is your intention? Is it to open a whole new window with another run button?

Comment: Why do you want to create/delete/create the group each time? Are the controls changing? If not, just make your run handler conditional on the value selected in `temp`.

Comment: @jav Thanks for your reply. Yes I want to run the same thing again except the value of x would always be True, so I don't want to use the gconfirm from the first line.

Comment: @jverzani I want to be again be able to select a program from the list of programs so I would need to run it from the start except asking the first line "Run Program" again.

Answer (score 1):

SOmething like this might get you what you want:

```
library(gWidgets2)

programs = list("Program A"="a.R",
    "Program B" = "b.R")

w <- gwindow("run programs")
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
fl <- gformlayout(cont=g)
cb <- gcombobox(names(programs), cont=fl, label="Select a program to run")
b <- gbutton("Run selected program", cont=fl, label="", handler=function(h,...) {
    prog <- svalue(cb)
    val <- gconfirm(sprintf("Run program %s?", prog), parent=w)
    if (val) {
        source(programs[[val]])
        gmessage("All done", parent=w)
    }
})
```